# Using Google Places to find location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, reverse-geocoding, google-places

I want to use Google places to capture my location name in android(not map. Because it didn't capture the streets and villages properly). but i don't know how to use google places in my application. Note that google places will not be displayed on my application. When I'll run my application it will display the location at one textview. How to do that.

please explain with sample code

Comment: i asked for google places not maps

Comment: ohh.sorry..i think you want to display areaname and streetname based on lat and long

Comment: why don't you try to display place based on GPS ?

Comment: Gps didn't provide the exact area. It often provides null

Comment: I need to identify the nearest village at least. But no way